# What is the difference between Swarga and Moksha?

Tags: moksha, afterlife, swarga

What is the difference between Swarga and Moksha?

Are they inter-related or the same thing? If not, when one reaches swarga, how does one attain Moksha because there is no scope to practice Dharma and Karma over there?

Comment: You have to return back to earth from Swarga after your Punya are finished. You may live ever for 1 Manvantar in heaven, but you are destined to return back to earth at expiry of Punya. But in Moksha you are ever free and there is no no returning back in cycle of birth and death.

Comment: I don't think Moksha can be attained in Swarga, as far as I've read Scriptures. Earth is said to be only realm giving moksha, and there also, Bharatavarsha (India is a part of Bharatvarsh, not the whole Bharatvarsh) is said to be most meritful. It is said that in other Varshas people always enjoy like Treta Yuga.